# Python code with requests.get().json() runs infinitely

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I have the following code to scrape data from a table on https://www.nba.com/stats/

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json

headers = {'Host': 'stats.nba.com','User-Agent': 'Firefox/55.0','Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*','Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5','Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate','Referer': 'https://stats.nba.com/','x-nba-stats-origin': 'stats','x-nba-stats-token': 'true','DNT': '1',}

url = 'https://stats.nba.com/stats/leaguedashplayerstats?College=&Conference=&Country=&DateFrom=&DateTo=&Division=&DraftPick=&DraftYear=&GameScope=&GameSegment=&Height=&LastNGames=0&LeagueID=00&Location=&MeasureType=Base&Month=0&OpponentTeamID=0&Outcome=&PORound=0&PaceAdjust=N&PerMode=PerGame&Period=0&PlayerExperience=&PlayerPosition=&PlusMinus=N&Rank=N&Season=2020-21&SeasonSegment=&SeasonType=Regular+Season&ShotClockRange=&StarterBench=&TeamID=0&TwoWay=0&VsConference=&VsDivision=&Weight='

json = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json() # the line which the code never gets past

data = json['resultSets'][0]['rowSet']
columns = json['resultSets'][0]['headers']

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data, columns=columns)
```

This code used to properly create a DataFrame from the data on the site, but it no longer does and it doesn't output an error either. I use JupyterLab to run the code and it just runs infinitely.

My guess is that the headers are outdated in some way, but I'm not sure how to go about updating them.

Comment: `requests.get()` will wait untill it gets a result. It might be because of the headers.

Comment: Does that url even exist? It timed out in my browser.

Comment: As suggested by Antoine, most likely your url is wrong or out of date, so then request is not able to reach the site you're looking for. Requests has some built in timeouts that should eventually trigger (I think) causing the request to fail

Comment: @Antoine Yeah that always happened in the past. It's the URL that pops up when you right click the table, inspect, go to network and then XHR and then refresh. The process used to find the URL still works on a page like this https://www.nba.com/stats/players/traditional/?sort=PTS&dir=-1

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out after posting the question. I was indeed using outdated headers.

```
headers = {'Host': 'stats.nba.com',
'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
'x-nba-stats-token': 'true',
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Mobile Safari/537.36',
'x-nba-stats-origin': 'stats',
'Origin': 'https://www.nba.com',
'Referer': 'https://www.nba.com/',
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9}'}
```

If you use these headers in the above code, the script runs as intended!

Comment: And for anyone in the future who does not know how to find the updated headers (in case these too become outdated in the future), this link shows how you can find the request headers in google chrome developer tools. https://towardsdatascience.com/how-scraping-nba-stats-is-cooler-than-michael-jordan-49d7562ce3ef